# Imprecise output when calculating dBFS value from 16-bit audio sample value using C#

Tags: c#, math, audio, audio-processing, decibel

I am calculating a dBFS value from a 16-bit wave file sample (-32768 to +32767) using c# as follows:

```
int sampleValue = -32700;

double dBFSvalue = 20 * Math.Log10(Math.Abs(sampleValue) / 32768);
```

But when I try to print the dBFS value, a sampleValue of 32768 results in "0" as it should, but any other value of sampleValue results in "-infinity".

```
MessageBox.Show($"Result: {dBFSvalue}dBFS");
```

Is this something to do with the displaying of type Double?
How should I convert the number to display it properly in the form of "-60.5 dBFS"?

Thanks.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your second line of code by

```
double dBFSvalue = 20 * Math.Log10(Math.Abs(sampleValue) / 32768.0);
```

You need the `.0` to calculate it as floating point number. Otherwise it is calculated as integer and the term in the brackets is evaluated as 0.

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I've made that mistake before and I seem to keep forgetting.